# Performing String parsing with TEXT DataType

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using TEXT datatype in SQL

Working on SQL 2000, I would like to perform the following

```
Select @String = SUBSTRING(@String, @idx + DATALENGTH(@firstDelimiter)/ 2,LEN(@String))
```

NOTE: @String is a type TEXT , @FirstDelimiter is of type Varchar(4).

Why am I unable to run the above code? How do I perform the above instead?

Is the above equivalent to this below

```
SET @String = RIGHT(@String,  LEN(@String) - (@FoundIndex + DATALENGTH(@FirstDelimeter) / 2))
```

Comment: You realize that @firstDelimiter, nor DATALENGTH of, will give you a position in @String?   At most, the result will be four if @firstDelimiter is VARCHAR(4) before the division...

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you want to do? SUBSTRING will always return varchar (upto to 8000) of course, so LEN(@String) is moot if > 8000.

Comment: I am here trying to run a SUBSTRING routine supplying it with TEXT to potentially return TEXT. If I am unable to use SUBSTRING for this, what other way can I accomplish same?

Comment: You could try [READTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238511.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server 2000 `TEXT` data type does **not** support the usual string manipulation functions. This is just one of the many reasons that in later version of SQL Server, you should switch to `VARCHAR(MAX)` - that type will support all the usual string functions.

Unfortunately, with SQL Server 2000, you're stuck with the `TEXT` datatype, and if you use that data type, you're stuck with its very limited set of string functions - see documentation on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276838%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx).

As you can see, the `SUBSTRING` function is supported - but the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259342%28SQL.80%29.aspx) on that also clearly state that the return type of SUBSTRING is a `VARCHAR` type - not a `TEXT`.

String manipulation on SQL Server 2000's `TEXT` data type is an annoying nightmare - if you have any chance at all, upgrade to 2005 or newer and use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead - you'll spare yourself a lot of grief and wasted hours.....